Can Dar Al Islam Revert Back To Dar Al Harb/Dar Al Kufr
As per fuqaha of 4 Madhab can Dar Al Islam revert Back To Dar Al Kufr/Dar Al Harb? What Is the Majority Opinion among Fuqaha
Note: Would Prefer Hanbali Position

تحوّل دار الإسلام إلى دار كفر
6 - اختلف الفقهاء في تحوّل دار الإسلام إلى دار للكفر‏.‏
فقال الشّافعيّة‏:‏ لا تصير دار الإسلام دار كفر بحال من الأحوال، وإن
استولى عليها الكفّار، وأجلوا المسلمين عنها، وأظهروا فيها أحكامهم‏.‏
لخبر‏:‏ «الإسلام يعلو ولا يعلى عليه» وقال المالكيّة، والحنابلة، وصاحبا
أبي حنيفة ‏"‏ أبو يوسف، ومحمّد ‏"‏‏:‏ تصير دار الإسلام دار كفر بظهور
أحكام الكفر فيها‏.‏
وذهب أبو حنيفة إلى أنّه لا تصير دار كفر إلاّ بثلاث شرائط‏:‏
أ - ظهور أحكام الكفر فيها‏.‏
ب - أن تكون متاخمةً لدار الكفر‏.‏
ج - أن لا يبقى فيها مسلم، ولا ذمّيّ آمناً بالأمان الأوّل، وهو أمان
المسلمين‏.‏
ووجه قول الصّاحبين ومن معهما أنّ دار الإسلام ودار الكفر‏:‏ أضيفتا إلى
الإسلام وإلى الكفر لظهور الإسلام أو الكفر فيهما، كما تسمّى الجنّة دار
السّلام، والنّار دار البوار، لوجود السّلامة في الجنّة، والبوار في
النّار، وظهور الإسلام والكفر إنّما هو بظهور أحكامهما، فإذا ظهرت أحكام
الكفر في دار فقد صارت دار كفر، فصحّت الإضافة، ولهذا صارت الدّار دار
إسلام بظهور أحكام الإسلام فيها من غير شريطة أخرى، فكذا تصير دار كفر
بظهور أحكام الكفر فيها‏.‏
ووجه قول أبي حنيفة‏:‏ أنّ المقصود من إضافة الدّار إلى الإسلام والكفر
ليس هو عين الإسلام والكفر، وإنّما المقصود هو‏:‏ الأمن، والخوف،
ومعناه‏:‏ أنّ الأمن إن كان للمسلمين في الدّار على الإطلاق والخوف
لغيرهم على الإطلاق فهي دار إسلام، وإن كان الأمن فيها لغير المسلمين على
الإطلاق والخوف للمسلمين على الإطلاق فهي دار كفر، فالأحكام عنده مبنيّة
على الأمان والخوف، لا على الإسلام والكفر، فكان اعتبار الأمن والخوف
أولى‏.‏ وينظر التّفصيل في ‏(‏دار الحرب‏)‏‏.‏
دخول الحربيّ دار الإسلام
7 - ليس للحربيّ دخول دار الإسلام إلاّ بإذن من الإمام أو نائبه، فإن
استأذن في دخولها فإن كان في دخوله مصلحة، كإبلاغ رسالة، أو سماع كلام
اللّه تعالى، أو حمل ميرة أو متاع يحتاج إليهما المسلمون، جاز الإذن له
بدخول دار الإسلام إلاّ الحرم، ولا يقيم في الحجاز أكثر من ثلاثة أيّام،
لأنّ ما زاد على هذه المدّة في حكم الإقامة، وهو غير جائز‏.‏ وفي غير
الحجاز يقيم قدر الحاجة‏.‏ أمّا الحرم فلا يجوز دخول كافر فيه وإن كان
ذمّيًّا بحال من الأحوال عند جمهور الفقهاء‏.‏ لقوله تعالى‏:‏ ‏{‏يَا
أَيُّهَا الَّذِينَ آمَنُواْ إِنَّمَا الْمُشْرِكُونَ نَجَسٌ فَلاَ
يَقْرَبُواْ الْمَسْجِدَ الْحَرَامَ بَعْدَ عَامِهِمْ هَـذَا‏}‏‏.‏
وللتّفصيل ينظر‏:‏ ‏(‏أرض العرب، حرم‏)‏‏.‏

Source: كتاب: الموسوعة الفقهية الكويتية

This site is not a translation service. Therefore your request is rather off-topic. If you need translation or explanation or have an inquiry on a specific statement (sentence, word, word combination) this would be acceptable, but not for a whole chapter, page paragraph etc..

I think I worded in wrong way and created confusion.
Updated The Quesiton

This, as is written is still a translation request. I think the keyword is the verb ظهر and the key sentence is  "ظهور أحكام الكفر ", with the explanation of their meaning the points can be clarified. In fact there are in summary 5 views, one held by abu Hanifa, one by the shafi'is, one by the majority including hanbali scholars, one at least best explained by the maliki scholar ad-Dasuqi and one "invented" by ibn Taymiyyah, In each of the views the assignment of the situation and its particularities plays a role.
